# How to create a block with random products and style grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, products

I'm starting to play with magento 2 and wanted to create a list of 10 random products that I can place anywhere (e.g. home) with a grid style. May I know, How I can get 10 random products, but I don't know, how I can display them with grid style (I only have product information)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pretty simple answer, since Magento handles the frontend in a particular way. But I would say you should review a post like this: https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-use-viewmodels-in-magento-2/

and to get what you want to achieve you should:

1. Create a view model to get the data
2. Create a template file (.phtml file), you call the view model from this file
3. Create a block in a page layout (.xml files) to configure the ViewModel and call the template file.
4. Then you can style it as you want from the template file. I you want to add css, I recommend that you use less.